# file_get_contents with HTTPS

Tags: php, https, file-get-contents, php-7

I upgraded my Ubuntu box from 14.04 LTS to 16.04 LTS. This made me switch from php5 to php7.0.

Since  the upgrade, when I use `file_get_contents` on an HTTPS resource, I get the following error:

> PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(https://www.google.com/): failed to open stream: Connection timed out

Since it was working with php5 I think It's a configuration problem. I checked in `phpinfo()` that the SSL extension is enabled. Maybe something to set in the `php.ini`?

**Edit** (details from the comments):

- openssl is in the list returned by `php -m`
- php.ini contains the line `allow_url_fopen = On`

Comment: "connection timed out" usually points to a firewall problem.

Comment: You need to be more specific with the original php version. Some defaults have changed over time.

Comment: use this: ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); //300 seconds = 5 minutes

Comment: @apokryfos Must have been 5.5.9, the most up to date version in 14.04.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider `ufw` is not installed and I temporarily cleared my `iptables` rules: no change. Do you think of anything else that could block the traffic?

Comment: @RohitDhiman um, it just increases the timeout?

Comment: Is OpenSSL (or anything that allows HTTPS streams to be opened) installed and enabled in PHP (check `php -m` for OpenSSL or similar).

Comment: @apokryfos yes, openssl is in the list given by `php -m`.

Comment: Is [`allow_url_fopen`](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) enabled?

Comment: One last thing (and then I'm out of ideas officially). Make sure `stream_get_wrappers` returns `https` in the list .

Comment: @apokryfos yes it does, its even the first item. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Try running `telnet www.google.com 443` on the server. If it connects, it's a PHP problem. If it doesn't it's a network problem.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Looks definitely like a network problem then. What's weird is that `curl` is working fine.

Comment: maybe ipv4 works and ipv6 doesn't, or vice versa ... there are so many possible reasons that it's only guessing with the currently available information.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider that's it! Seems like IPv6 outgoing connexions are failing (incoming works fine). Now I have to find why. Thanks !